# Smallest rectangle inscribing Young tableaux

Tags: integer-partitions, young-tableaux

I am interested in knowing the name of any of this characteristics of a Young tableaux (Ferrer's diagram): Smallest rectangle that contains it or the area of such a rectangle. For instance:

Partition (3,2,2,1,1):

1

1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1

is contained in rectangle 3x5 as per 3 is its longest part and is formed by 5 parts. Consequently, corresponding rectangle's area is 15.

Some literature about it, normally related to integer partitions classification, would be also much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "that inscribe it" : it is not clear ; maybe you mean that "contain it" ? Take an example please.

Comment: Thanks for the precisions. I think you simply have to consider the dual partition $(5,3,1)$, then multiply the leading coefficient $5$ by the leading coefficient $3$ of the initial partition.

Comment: It is another way to explain same calculation as largest part in a partition becomes number of parts in its dual partition and viceversa.